# Actionbar homeAsUpIndicator background

Tags: colors, background, android-actionbar

I am using this code in styles.xml but my button background does not change.
Where i am doing wrong?

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/actionbar_buttonbg</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can not add a background to homeAsUpIndicator via styles.xml.

However you can do it programatically:

```
public void setHomeAsUpBackgroundResource(int resource) {

    View abView = findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
    if (abView != null && abView instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup vgAb = (ViewGroup) abView;
        if (vgAb.getChildCount() > 0) {
            View child = vgAb.getChildAt(0);
            if (child != null && child instanceof ImageButton)
                child.setBackgroundResource(resource);
        }
    }
}
```

It is hacky: it relies on two assumptions: this button is the first child of the action bar and  is an instance of ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Hi  try use  in style properties actionBarItemBackground  good luck



<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/actionbar_buttonbg</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@color/backGroundHomeAsUp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@color/backGroundHomeAsUp</item>
</style>
```